# performSegueWithIdentifier from NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift2, nsurlsession

I'm trying to find a proper way to iterate through data from a NSURLSession to create a User object.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
        return
    }


    self.handleLoginAttempt(data!)
    print("Finished Login Attempt!")
}

task.resume()


func handleLoginAttempt(data: NSData) {
    // Iterate through data.
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoggedInSuccessfully", sender: nil)
}
```

Now, it goes to the next View controller properly, however it just hangs.  I put print statements at the end (`print("Finished Login Attempt!")`) as you can see and in the `viewDidLoad()` and I see the statement from the viewDidLoad of the new ViewController, but never the "Finished Login Attempt".  So I'm assuming I am doing the NSURLSession incorrectly, given that this is probably a fairly basic set of actions for an app.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try run it on MainThread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.handleLoginAttempt(data!)
    print("Finished Login Attempt!")
})
```

Comment: Would I put that within the NSURLSession?